# How do I ensure that typedefs in a template are also swigged?

Tags: c++, templates, typedef, swig, typename

I am wrapping a C++ class ([PointMatcher.h](https://github.com/ethz-asl/libpointmatcher/blob/master/pointmatcher/PointMatcher.h)) for C# using SWIG. I have used the `%template` directive to concretise a template class as follows:

```
%include "../pointmatcher/PointMatcher.h"

%template(PointMatcherFloat) PointMatcher<float>;
```

However, it turns out the template `PointMatcher<T>` contains typedefs and typenames based on `<T>` and these are not being included in the SWIG wrapper. (Specifically, I need access to `TransformationParameters` below.)

```
//! The scalar type
typedef T ScalarType;
//! A vector over ScalarType
typedef typename Eigen::Matrix<T, Eigen::Dynamic, 1> Vector;
//! A vector of vector over ScalarType, not a matrix
typedef std::vector<Vector, Eigen::aligned_allocator<Vector> > VectorVector;
//! A quaternion over ScalarType
typedef typename Eigen::Quaternion<T> Quaternion;
//! A vector of quaternions over ScalarType
typedef std::vector<Quaternion, Eigen::aligned_allocator<Quaternion> > QuaternionVector;
//! A dense matrix over ScalarType
typedef typename Eigen::Matrix<T, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> Matrix;
//! A dense integer matrix
typedef typename Eigen::Matrix<int, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> IntMatrix;

//! A matrix holding the parameters a transformation.
/**
    The transformation lies in the special Euclidean group of dimension \f$n\f$, \f$SE(n)\f$, implemented as a dense matrix of size \f$n+1 \times n+1\f$ over ScalarType.
*/
typedef Matrix TransformationParameters;

// alias for scope reasons
typedef PointMatcherSupport::Parametrizable Parametrizable; //!< alias
typedef Parametrizable::Parameters Parameters; //!< alias
typedef Parametrizable::ParameterDoc ParameterDoc; //!< alias
typedef Parametrizable::ParametersDoc ParametersDoc; //!< alias
typedef Parametrizable::InvalidParameter InvalidParameter; //!< alias
```

I have tried duplicating the declarations above as an `%inline` block, using `T` and `float`. (As described in the [SWIG 3.0 documentation on typedef](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#SWIG_nn20).) In both cases the typedefs are simply included in the .cxx file, but no associated classes or methods are generated.

How do I make sure these types are made available in PointMatcherFloat?

---

Edit note: I previously thought this was about member templates (like [How to instantiate a template method of a template class with swig?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16218929/how-to-instantiate-a-template-method-of-a-template-class-with-swig) and [How to get SWIG to apply templates when wrapping a template class containing vectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29699543/how-to-get-swig-to-apply-templates-when-wrapping-a-template-class-containing-vec)) but it's actually about typedefs/typenames within a template.

Comment: Addendum: while working on another method I discovered that the typedef I'm interested in (TransformationParameters) is in fact being generated as SWIGTYPE_p_Eigen__MatrixT_float_Eigen__Dynamic_Eigen__Dynamic_t. How can I rename it TransformationParametersFloat and have it appear within the concretised PointMatcherFloat class?

Comment: You can use the `%rename` syntax or explicit instantiate member functions, member types etc, e.g. `%template (SomeClassSomeMemberFunction) SomeClass::SomeMemberFunction<float>` similarly for typedef's within classes. A word of advice though is to create a pure C wrapper of the functions from Eigen that you want to expose - it is so much simpler

Comment: @JensMunk thanks - what order do I make the rename and/or template calls in (relative to my existing template call)

Comment: As I suggested, I would create a function, which is a non-template function, which requires more simple types on its interface and wrap this instead, e.g. a function with prototype `SomeFunction(T**, size_t, size_t,....)` and wrap the 3 first arguments to a matrix in the target language, e.g. a NumPy matrix in Python.

Comment: An example of renaming nested templates is given here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9757642/wrapping-specialised-c-template-class-with-swig